# XML PATH in SQL SERVER how to NEST

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm new to using XML and I think this is an easy question, but i just can't get the format correct.

I'm trying to get this output

```
<Contracts>
  <Contract>
    <Ref>P000006-140</Ref>
    <ReportingTransactionAmountEntry>
      <TechAccountAmtItem>
        <Amt Ccy="GBP">7500.0000</Amt>
      </TechAccountAmtItem>
    </ReportingTransactionAmountEntry>
  </Contract>
  <Contract>
    <Ref>P000006-140</Ref>
    <ReportingTransactionAmountEntry>
      <TechAccountAmtItem>
       <Amt Ccy="GBP">100.0000</Amt>
      </TechAccountAmtItem>
      <TechAccountAmtItem>
        <Amt Ccy="GBP">7600.0000</Amt>
      </TechAccountAmtItem>
    </ReportingTransactionAmountEntry>
  </Contract>
  <Contract>
    <Ref>P000006-140</Ref>
    <ReportingTransactionAmountEntry>
      <TechAccountAmtItem>
        <Amt Ccy="EUR">500.0000</Amt>
      </TechAccountAmtItem>
    </ReportingTransactionAmountEntry>
  </Contract>
</Contracts>
```

to look like this,
with the contact Reference only showing once at a higher level

```
<Contracts>
  <Contract>
    <Ref>P000006-140</Ref>
        <ReportingTransactionAmountEntry>
          <TechAccountAmtItem>
            <Amt Ccy="GBP">7500.0000</Amt>
          </TechAccountAmtItem>
        </ReportingTransactionAmountEntry>
        <ReportingTransactionAmountEntry>
          <TechAccountAmtItem>
            <Amt Ccy="GBP">100.0000</Amt>
          </TechAccountAmtItem>
          <TechAccountAmtItem>
            <Amt Ccy="GBP">7600.0000</Amt>
          </TechAccountAmtItem>
        </ReportingTransactionAmountEntry>
        <ReportingTransactionAmountEntry>
          <TechAccountAmtItem>
            <Amt Ccy="EUR">500.0000</Amt>
          </TechAccountAmtItem>
        </ReportingTransactionAmountEntry>
  </Contract>
</Contracts>
```

my query looks like this

```
    SELECT 
        RTRIM(PolicyRef) AS  'Ref', 
            (SELECT * FROM
                (
                    select
                    RTRIM(SettlementCurrency) AS 'TechAccountAmtItem/Amt/@Ccy',
                    Paid_This_Time_Indemnity AS 'TechAccountAmtItem/Amt'
                    UNION
                    SELECT
                    RTRIM(SettlementCurrency) AS 'TechAccountAmtItem/Amt/@Ccy',
                    Paid_To_Date_Indemnity AS 'TechAccountAmtItem/Amt'
                ) iq FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
             ) AS 'ReportingTransactionAmountEntry' 
    FROM #tmpClm3   
    FOR XML PATH ('Contract'),ROOT('Contracts')
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group on `PolicyRef` in the main query and get the details in a sub-query.

```sql
select T1.PolicyRef as [Ref],
       (
       select 
         (
         select T2.SettlementCurrency as [TechAccountAmtItem/Amt/@Ccy],
                T2.Paid_This_Time_Indemnity as [TechAccountAmtItem/Amt]
         where T2.Paid_This_Time_Indemnity is not null
         for xml path(''), type
         ),
         (
         select T2.SettlementCurrency as [TechAccountAmtItem/Amt/@Ccy],
                T2.Paid_To_Date_Indemnity as [TechAccountAmtItem/Amt]
         where T2.Paid_To_Date_Indemnity is not null
         for xml path(''), type
         )
       from T as T2
       where T1.PolicyRef = T2.PolicyRef
       for xml path('ReportingTransactionAmountEntry'), type
       )
from T as T1
group by T1.PolicyRef
for xml path('Contract'), root('Contracts')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c1b1/1)

Comment: thanks for responding to my queation. So what would you do in your example to make the <Ref> at a highr level, so that it is not repeated for each <ReportingtransactionEntry> ?

Comment: @user3722414 I misunderstood what output you where looking for. I have updated the answer.